# Git merging specified commits

Tags: git, tfs, branch, branching-and-merging, tfvc

In classical TFVC branching; every development check-ins are made into DEV branch. And when the developer wants to send his changes to TEST environment, he merges his changes to TEST branch. And when he wants to send this changes to production, he merges his changes to PROD branch. He manually selects those changes in TFS GUI. This method is good for the fact "**If I do not merge my change, I am sure it is not going to be deployed to the corresponding environment**".

However, in Git merging, there is no option to choose which commits to merge. So when the developer merges his feature commits to develop branch, those commits could easily be sent to master branch **by a future merge of another developer.**

In Git, how can I create a branching strategy so that I can select which commits to merge?

Answer (score 1):

Git supports [Cherry Pick merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). This method will allow you to pick individual changes and merge them into another branch. Another option is to do an [interactive rebase of the desired changes onto another branch](https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/git-rebase/). This mechanism will allow you to replay changes from one branch (preferably a feature or topic branch that isn't shared with the whole team) onto another branch.

The promotion level branch pattern, however, is a bit outdated and doesn't fit the distributed nature of Git really well (in a distributed version control world, which environment, who merged the code, where in the world). You may want to look into a number of other patterns. With the capability to do binary promotion (using the same bytes to run on DEV, TEST and PROD), containerization (where even the host infra moves along that path), Infra as Code and Config as Code allowing you to spin up environments easily, not having to rely soley on a pipeline through a fixed set of environments; that and git's ability to isolate smaller feature branches far more easily than in TFVC, the old promotion level branch model is no longer up to par. Sorry ;/

Microsoft recently documented [Release Flow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/04/19/release-flow-how-we-do-branching-on-the-vsts-team/), a lightweight model which does isolate the release candidates and cherry-picks subsequent fixes as the branch matures.

GitHub has also released documentation round their branch/merge process process. They've called it [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

You'll probably also find a lot of references for GitFlow, which has been very popular and matches a promotion level strategy a bit more. Yet many people are slowly turning their back on it due to the long-livity of a number of branches in this model and its relative complexity.

Reasons for these other model have to do with the far easier higher-frequency deliveries that are enabled by this model and the higher confidence that what you've tested on one environment is the same as you're releasing to another. Practices like Continuous Integration and Automated Testing can help ensure the quality of your existing code while making changes and other practices like temporary feature flags will allow you to release work that isn't yet completed while ensuring it remains turned off. Hence, instead of trying to completely isolate specific half-integrated changes from individual developers, these new practices try to increase integration between developers much more often and faster, allowing you to move smaller changes quicker. The isolation is either achieved by delaying a merge slightly or by not delaying at all and achieving isolation through other mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a few comments to @jessehouwing's excellent response.

There is a lot of religious "cherry-picking is not the git way" rhetoric out there. It is definitely true that git merging works better in git, in fact it would be easier in any revision control system, due to the file conflict issues that can arise much more easily with out-of-order cherry-picks. But just because something is easier, or because it works for certain open source workflows, does not mean that it is the only way or even that it is inherently better.

The cherry-pick route is definitely more difficult, and you've got to be sure that your processes, for whatever reason, needs that extra complexity. Otherwise it is definitely not worth it. But if you do...

The biggest trouble with cherry-picking, that is unfortunately not discussed in the Microsoft article, is that you are much more likely to run into conflicts. A couple of changes modify the same line of code and you try to port them out of order... conflicts. If you are a big organization, you could run into this a *lot*. The advice I'd give you at this point is this:

1. You cannot permit manual conflict resolution. This is because once you have one manual conflict resolution, the source and destination branches are different, and you have just compounded your future conflict problems. Instead, what you need is to ensure that any 'blocking' commits get cherry-picked into the destination branch first. (*)
2. You will need to make tools to automatically try cherry-picking all possible commits, identifying potential blocking commits and ensuring that all blocking commits in a chain are "ready to go" (whatever determines that in your process). (A person tasked with this job will quickly get overwhelmed.)

This is a very brief outline of some of the issues a cherry-picking workflow faces, but if you keep it as a guide, you'll discover the details quickly enough on your own.

(*) Depending on your workflow this might not be possible. If something was not ready for cherry-picking because it involves not having regulatory approval yet, for instance. But if it is just "a tester has not tested it yet", then the tester needs to be encouraged to test it asap.